# What does the m! in this perl syntax mean

Tags: perl

While trying to debug an issue I am having with git-svn and the --ignore-paths option, I've run into this perl expression that I don't understand and haven't been able to find anything similar in perl documentation.

```
$path =~ m!$self->{ignore_regex}!
```

My understanding of this is that this is matching the $path string to the ignore_regex but it doesn't seem to match anything the way I expect. The part that I don't understand is the `m! !` around `$self->{ignore_regex}`?

How should I be reading this syntax?

Comment: `m!....!` is the same as `/.../`,  the `!` just  confines the regex. See the documentation for [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: You don't even need the `m!!` for this expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [match operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

`m!...!` is more commonly written as `/.../`, but they are 100% identical.

> If `"/"` is the delimiter then the initial `m` is optional. With the `m` you can use any pair of non-whitespace (ASCII) characters as delimiters. This is particularly useful for matching path names that contain `"/"`, to avoid LTS (leaning toothpick syndrome). [...]

For example, the following are identical:

```perl
$path =~ /$self->{ignore_regex}/
$path =~ m/$self->{ignore_regex}/
$path =~ m^$self->{ignore_regex}^
$path =~ m{$self->{ignore_regex}}
```

The code in question checks if the string in `$path` matches the regex pattern in `$self->{ignore_regex}`.